# Laravel listening for package event

Tags: php, laravel, events, listener

I want to listen for an event fired by a package ([Laravel impersonate](https://github.com/404labfr/laravel-impersonate)).

When I set up my EventServiceProvider like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Listeners\LogImpersonation;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Lab404\Impersonate\Events\TakeImpersonation;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        TakeImpersonation::class => [
            LogImpersonation::class,
        ]
    ];

    /**
     * Register any events for your application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        //
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Listeners\LogImpersonation::handle() must be
>   an instance of App\Events\TakeImpersonation, instance of
>   Lab404\Impersonate\Events\TakeImpersonation given

My LogImpersonation:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\TakeImpersonation;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class LogImpersonation
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  TakeImpersonation  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(TakeImpersonation $event)
    {
        Log::info($event->impersonator->name . ' ingelogd als ' . $event->impersonated);
    }
}
```

I can't imagine I have to move the event, this is my first attempt at using events, so I must be missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you *exactly* what’s wrong:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Listeners\LogImpersonation::handle() must be an instance of App\Events\TakeImpersonation, instance of Lab404\Impersonate\Events\TakeImpersonation given

So your `App\Listeners\LogImpersonation::handle()` method was expecting an instance of `App\Events\TakeImpersonation` to be given, but instead got `Lab404\Impersonate\Events\TakeImpersonation`.

You need to update your listener class to import the proper class. So in your imports at the top, swap `App\Events\TakeImpersonation` (which is wrong and won’t exist in your application) for `Lab404\Impersonate\Events\TakeImpersonation` (the fully-qualified name of the package event you’re actually listening for).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `LogImpersonation@handle` method - it takes `$event` argument typed as `App\Events\TakeImpersonation`. To solve the error this class must be derived from package's `Lab404\Impersonate\Events\TakeImpersonation`.

If you don't need to extend package event class then you can delete your `App\Events\TakeImpersonation` version and use package version by changing `use` statement in the file with `LogImpersonation`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Lab404\Impersonate\Events\TakeImpersonation; // here
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class LogImpersonation
{
```